# DNS Records for separated hosting and mail server

Tags: email, dns

I host my site at a VPS. Because I'm no system admin or sort, I don't want to use my own VPS to host my emails because I lack technical knowledge and expertise to maintain a mail server. I also have a shared hosting plan where I have another domain and use the cPanel and emails perfectly for years without a problem.

So, I was wondering if it would be possible to use my **VPS** to host my site and my **SHARED** hosting account to host my emails.

To try it out, on Namecheap DNS settings I made the following entries:

- A Record       | @ 
      |  VPS_IP_ADDRESS
- A Record       | www   |  VPS_IP_ADDRESS
- A Record       | mail   |  SHARED_IP_ADDRESS
- TXT Record   | mail  |  v=spf1 +a +mx +ip4:SHARED_IP_ADDRESS ~all
- TXT Record   | default._domainkey.mail | v=DKIM; k=rsa; p=*******
- CNAME Record | mail  | example.com.
- MX Record        | mail  | example.com. 0

However, I think I'm missing something here. Would appreciate your help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The primary lookup key is the domain name, so for clarity let's swap columns in your zone:

```
NAME  → TYPE    DATA
------  ------  -------------------------------------------
@       A       VPS_IP_ADDRESS

mail    A       SHARED_IP_ADDRESS
mail    CNAME   example.com
mail    MX      0 example.com.
mail    TXT     "v=spf1 +a +mx +ip4:SHARED_IP_ADDRESS ~all"

www     A       VPS_IP_ADDRESS
```

Now some problems should become more obvious.

The records for your website are okay – both the bare domain, and the `www` subdomain, have A records pointing to the web server. However, your mail setup is a complete mess.

#### The CNAME record

CNAME means "completely alias this subdomain to `example.com`". In your situation that's 1) undesirable, since it'd add a wrong A record to the `mail` subdomain; 2) illegal, since you cannot mix CNAME and non-CNAME records on the same subdomain, 3) illegal, because the `mail` subdomain will be the target of MX, which doesn't allow CNAMEs.

Delete it.

#### The MX record

When people send mail to `something@example.com`, they will look for a MX record on `example.com` – that is, the exact same domain as in the recipient's address. They *will not* look under some miscellaneous subdomain.

Your current MX record is backwards; it's on the `mail` subdomain, pointing to the root domain (so incoming mail will never reach the shared-hosting server). You should change it to be the other way around:

```
NAME    TYPE    DATA
------  ------  -------------------------------------------
@       MX      0 mail.example.com.
mail    A       SHARED_IP_ADDRESS
```

(Well, unless you want your address to be "something@mail.example.com"... But I doubt that.)

#### The "spf1" TXT record

When people receive mail from `something@example.com`, *again* they will look for a "spf1" TXT record on `example.com`, exactly as in the sender's address. So your current record is also in the wrong place: it should be under the bare domain.

```
NAME    TYPE    DATA
------  ------  -------------------------------------------
@       TXT     "v=spf1 +this +that ~all"
```

Its contents are also somewhat redundant. You don't need `+a`, unless you're planning the web VPS itself to be sending mail directly. (But it shouldn't be doing that – it should go through the shared-hosting provider's SMTP server, so that messages can be properly DKIM-signed.)

You also shouldn't need both `+mx` and `+ip4:SHARED_IP_ADDRESS`, because your MX record will be pointing to that IP address *anyway*.

#### The "DKIM" TXT record

This seems to be correct – assuming you obtained it from the shared-hosting email provider.

Comment: Thanks a million for all the clarifications. Can't believe I was mixing up things that much. Applying changes and will inform of the result shortly. Thanks again.